# Get count of users who have not been billed since a certain month

Tags: sql

I'm pretty sure the title is horribly written, but I have NO clue how to word it, nor my question. We are having an issue where it seems some users haven't been billed for a few months. Not all, just some, and we are trying to figure out how many. For example, there is a current, active user who has not been billed for about 3 months. There is another who hasn't been billed for about 5+ months. There's also a few where they just didn't get billed last month, and etc...

I've been looking around, and because I'm pretty sure I'm not working my Google search correctly, I'm not finding a solution. After trying so many, the query I keep coming back to is:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT u.USER_ID) from SUBSCRIPTION AS s
JOIN USERS as U
ON s.USER_ID = u.USER_ID
WHERE s.BILLING_DATE <= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()) AND u.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
```

The above query, I believe is getting a much larger number than we should be getting back.

Comment: Start by finding the users (list of `user_id`) who have been billed within that period.  Now `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND user_id NOT IN (the first query);`  Hint: That first query only requires searching the `subscription` table.  Don't forget to tag the question with your specific database and mention the version as well.

Comment: Does a user have multiple subscription rows for each renewal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something to try.

Description of subquery:

Find the users which have been billed within the last month or so.

Description of the outer query expression:

Find the count of active users not in the above list of users which have been billed.

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM users
 WHERE STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
   AND user_id NOT IN (
          SELECT user_id FROM subscription
           WHERE BILLING_DATE > DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
       )
;
```

Adjust the `dateadd` logic as needed.

Comment: I believe this is what I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to look at the most recent subscription?

```
with data as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by s.USER_ID order by s.BILLING_DATE desc) as rn
    from SUBSCRIPTION AS s inner join as s on u.USER_ID = s.USER_ID
    where u.STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
)
select *
from data
where rn = 1 and BILLING_DATE <= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE());
```